# How can I make msbuild understand that a .csproj file depends on the availability of an exe built by another .csproj

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a large VStudio solution whose `.csproj` files I'm porting over to the new .NET SDK format. I have integrated the `github` project with `AppVeyor`. When I work on the solution, my project is built by VStudio; `AppVeyor` uses msbuild to build my project.

All of the class library project files in the solution have been modified so that they specify `<TargetFrameworks>netStandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>`. For simplicity, let's represent the class library project files with `classlib.csproj`.

The solution also contains a few command-line tools, which need to be built in advance of some of the other projects, because those later projects need to run the command-line tools as a preprocessor before building themselves. These command-line projects are all specifying `<TargetFrameworks>net472;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>`. Let's represent the tool project files with `tool.csproj`.

In order to build correctly, `tool.csproj` needs to be built before `classlib.csproj`. In the solution I've used the `Build dependencies > Project dependencies` command in the VStudio solution explorer to indicate this. This works fine when I'm working inside of VStudio.

However, when I push my changes to `github`, `AppVeyor` kicks off an `msbuild` process to build the projects. From the error spew, it's clear that the `tool.csproj` didn't get built in time. It seems `msbuild` doesn't understand the project dependency information in the `.sln` file.

Reading what's posted on the intertubes (e.g. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe/), I attempted to add the following to `classlib.csproj`:

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="..\tool\tool.csproj"> 
    <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly> 
</ProjectReference>
```

But when I do this I get the error:

```
Project '..\tool\tool.csproj' targets 'net472;netcoreapp2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'
```

which clearly makes sense.

Some other solutions I've read suggest editing the `.sln` file so that `tool.csproj` gets built first, and hope that building will be completed before `classlib.csproj` starts building. However, this is a race condition since `msbuild` is not aware of the dependency.

How, then, do I express that `classlib.csproj` depends on `tool.csproj` so that `msbuild` understands it?

EDIT

It turns out the issue was caused by an interaction between the target I'd written to start my tool and the globbing operation MSBuild does to resolve the `<Compile>` item collection using a pattern similar to `**\*.cs`. The tool generated the file *after* the globbing operation. Since the generated file isn't present when the globbing happens, it is missing from the `<Compile>` item collection, and the build failed. I mistakenly interpreted the error "foo.cs not found" as a failure to execute the tool, when in fact, it's a timing issue.

Comment: Ensure you that your .sln file contains the project dependency wit something like :`Project("{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}") = "classlib", "..\classlib.csproj", "{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
 ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
  {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} = {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
 EndProjectSection
EndProject` and your .sln is used to build with msbuild

Comment: John, any update? I've checked it works for a solution with several .net framework projects. And if it not works for you situation with .net fx and .net standard, please let  me know. I will test it with your further info.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I'm still struggling with this. If you have the spare time, look at the `netStandard` branch of https://github.com/uxmal/reko and try building it with MsBuild.

Comment: Ok. I will try that on Monday.

Comment: @JohnKällén I tried to build according to the github link from you. But after i download it, too many folders in it, and I'm stuck with which solution to test. Cause some of them seems C++ and some of them only have .csproj without .sln. Could you tell which the certain folder can stand for your situation or you can  share a simple sample solution by one-drive, I will test it in both msbuild and appveyor.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT: perhaps we can take up the discussion in https://gitter.im/uxmal/reko?

Comment: @JohnKällén Hi john, does the issue persist? If it persist, any update you can share here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To make the build order works outside VS IDE, we need to use `add reference`
> instead of `BuildDependencies=>ProjectDependencies`.

Right-click classlib project and choose add=>reference, in Project node choose the Tool Project you want like this:

[image]

Click ok to add it and save changes. After that, open the classlib.csproj you can find sentence like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\xxx\Tools.csproj">
      <Project>{6eaa430f-9793-4639-a84b-6ab767d57147}</Project>
      <Name>Tools.csproj</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This what the msbuild can understand. And I think that's what you want.

> After that,you can use a single msbuild tool or Appveyor to check the
> build order.

And in Appveyor, we can also disable the paralell builds(settings=>build=>msbuild options) to make sure it won't build classlib.csproj until the tools.csproj build ends.
The final build order in Appveyor will be what we defined in VS. Hope it helps.